# Having multiple properties in json schema items

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to write the schema to have multiple properties, but unable to do so.
I tried to add another ref in additional properties but it also did not work.

It would be helpful if someone can point the right way to do it.

Trying to write JSON schema for :

```
[{
    "name": "hi",
    "metaData": {
        "value": true
    }
}, {
    "name": "hello",
    "metaData": {
        "value": true
    }
}]
```

the JSON schema I am trying to use is :

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "metadata":
    {
      "type":"object",
      "properties":{
        "value":{"type":"boolean"}
      }
    }

  },


  "title": "MetaData",
  "type": "array",
    "items": {

      "name":
      {
        "type":"string"
      },

     "additionalProperties": {
         "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata"


    } 
    },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the following schema :

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "metadata":
    {
      "type":"object",
      "properties":{
        "value":{"type":"boolean"}
      }
    }

  },


  "title": "MetaData",
  "type": "array",
    "items": {
     "type":"object",
       "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
       },
     "additionalProperties": {
         "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata"   
    } 
    },

}
```